# is AVERAGEIFS possible in Sharepoint calculated column list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

Sorry I'm new to SharePoint. I am building a tool to track projects and would just like to ask if it is possible to have a column to automatically average all projects with the same 'priority name' and 'quarter' (e.g. Q1, Q2, Q3..) that it belongs to.

The value at which these figures will be calculated will be coming from one column to be populated manually - 'project rating'.

Thank you in advance and more power!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula called [AVERAGEA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averagea-function-a5ae0aea-11ad-4bba-856a-031e08567df0), you can use it.

Have a try and let's know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is **No**.

`AVERAGEIFS` is not available in SharePoint calculated column formulas.

However, `AVERAGE` and `AVERAGEA` functions are available.

**[AVERAGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/average-function-73cdedbf-5954-492d-a32d-aa9fbc29c5ec)**:

> Returns the average (arithmetic mean) of the arguments.

**[AVERAGEA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averagea-function-a5ae0aea-11ad-4bba-856a-031e08567df0)**:

> Calculates the average (arithmetic mean) of the values in the list of arguments. Unlike the AVERAGE functions, text and logical values such as TRUE and FALSE are included in the calculation.

Check all common formulas available in SharePoint Lists:

[Examples of common formulas in SharePoint Lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Also, you can show **Average** of a list column in SharePoint list view by settings **Totals** in **View settings**.

You can add some filters in list view based on project, priority name and maybe some date fields and show the average of column in list view.

Check this if it helps you: [Creating List Views - Specify Totals for a View](http://guides.wmlcloud.com/technology/sharepoint-2013---creating-list-views---specify-totals-for-a-view.aspx).